# Div Position: Fixed. Absolute when certain length away?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently making a website with a "Support is Live" div which will be following the user when scrolling. So I gave it `Position: Fixed;` and all works fine.

But when the user scrolls back up, I want the Support div to stop so it doesn't "touch" the header.

Here is a picture that hopefully makes it easier to understand:

http://gyazo.com/2694b03181a39c3b6673901b42b5952d
I want the yellow div to stop in line with the orange field on the picture. But when the user starts to scrolling down again, it will follow.

My Best Regards
Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will need some JQuery to work properly:
**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/84aZQ/1/)**

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {    
  if($(document).scrollTop() < 100) { 

 $('#alert').addClass("absolute");

} else if($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {  //100 is the height of your header. Adjust if needed
 $('#alert').removeClass("absolute");

} 
});
```

**CSS**

```
.absolute {
top: 100px; //same as the value in the conditions
position: absolute;

}


#alert{

background-color: #FF0;     
float: left;    
height: 400px;  
width: 230px;   
margin-left: 20px; 
    position: fixed;
z-index:999;


}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="alert" class="absolute"> </div> 
/!-- add the class so that it doesn't mess up the layout when you load the page --!/
```

The srolltop function checks how much space is between your viewport and the top of your document. When it reaches the height of the header, a class `absolute` is applied in order to keep the `#alert` div in its place.

Comment: Hi, Am I doing this right?

`<div>
<script>
$(document).on("scroll", function() {    
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 0) { //if you scrolled more than 0 pixels

 $('#alert').addClass("supRuta");

} else
 $('#alert').removeClass("supRuta");


});
</script>
</div>`


Doesn't seem to work for me, but I'm quite new to Jquery as well

Here is the class for .supRuta:

`.supRuta {
 background-color: #FF0;
 float: left;
 height: 400px;
 width: 230px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 position: fixed;
}`

Comment: I updated my Answer, try this code and tell me how it is

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking your time :=)

Still doesn't work, but this is my code right now:

`<div id="SupRuta">
<script>
 $(document).on("scroll", function() {    
  if($(document).scrollTop() == 0) { 

 $('#SupRuta').addClass("absolute");

} else if($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {  //100 is the height of your header. Adjust if needed
 $('#SupRuta').removeClass("absolute");

} 
});
</script>
</div>`

And I made SupRuta to a ID, because that is what # is for in Jquery? Or am I completely wrong? :=)

Comment: I'll give you a more detailed description soon.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer and tested the solution.Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/84aZQ/1/